# Admob: no "impression" (android)

Tags: android, admob, andengine

I' ve followed all [the necessary steps](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?) for adding banner in my android application with Admob.

I 've registered my device as test device and banner is displayed as below :

[image: game over screen]

However, 5 days after publication on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nonomachi), I got this :

[image: admob screen]

In my test device, ad is never displayed :

[image]

Does someone know why impression rate is so low ?

My android code :

```
 // CREATING a Smart Banner View
 adView = new AdView(this);
 adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx");
 adView.setAdSize(AdSize.FULL_BANNER);
 adView.refreshDrawableState();

 AdRequest adRequest = new  AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxx").build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);

 frameLayout.addView(adView, adViewLayoutParams);
```

---

EDIT :

Here is the log (when calling ad without the addTestDevice method)

```
08-05 10:30:51.244: I/Ads(31127): No fill from ad server.
08-05 10:30:51.244: I/Ads(31127): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
08-05 10:30:51.244: W/Ads(31127): Failed to load ad: 3
08-05 10:31:51.300: I/Ads(31127): Starting ad request.
08-05 10:31:51.302: I/Ads(31127): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") to get test ads on this device.
08-05 10:31:51.313: I/Ads(31127): Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
08-05 10:31:51.322: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(31127): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-05 10:31:51.369: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(31127): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-05 10:31:51.411: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(31127): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-05 10:31:51.417: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(31127): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-05 10:31:51.881: I/Ads(31127): No fill from ad server.
08-05 10:31:51.883: I/Ads(31127): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
08-05 10:31:51.883: W/Ads(31127): Failed to load ad: 3
08-05 10:32:51.935: I/Ads(31127): Starting ad request.
08-05 10:32:51.937: I/Ads(31127): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") to get test ads on this device.
08-05 10:32:51.951: I/Ads(31127): Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
08-05 10:32:51.964: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(31127): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-05 10:32:52.007: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(31127): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-05 10:32:52.058: D/dalvikvm(31127): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1010K, 45% free 6137K/11120K, paused 4ms+7ms, total 46ms
08-05 10:32:52.080: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(31127): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-05 10:32:52.088: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(31127): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-05 10:32:52.587: I/Ads(31127): No fill from ad server.
08-05 10:32:52.588: I/Ads(31127): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
08-05 10:32:52.588: W/Ads(31127): Failed to load ad: 3
```

Thank you

Comment: Does your live app still showing test ads?

Comment: i dont know,similar thing happened with me,ive integrated one app,its always returning no fill in response,and adds are not shown,impression zero.

but my other app is showing adds.dont know the problem,but adds are showing if i use the legacy admob account.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Test banner is still displayed (on my test device) with my live app. Should I delete test device code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see

**request** in admob means how many times your advertise in app is get called (link hit)

**impression** in admob means how many times your called advertise get displayed to user

**clicks** in admob means how many time user clicked on your displayed advertise

now in your case request is **3527** means your ad get called by 3527 times but during this time only one impression happend means only one advertise get display to your app user

and there is no click counter means no any user get clicked on it

now you need to wait for 48 hours to data get updated(asper admob policy) but in your case already there is 5days finished so as per my understanding may be in your code there is bug like you are using testing mode

in xml ADVIEW tag you mentioned TEST mode so it is in testing mode not in real mode am not sure but you may chek it hope it will help you

Comment: I have deleted the TestDevice method and updated the new version... wait and see . Thank you for your precious help !

Comment: problem persists... something should be wrong in my code :-( I have added log info.

Comment: brother am not sure but as per my understanding i am giving my suggestion recently admob changes its configuration and its sdk also they changed their way of integration now they want google play service into android project  as i saw your logcat their clearly mentioned that google play service not included so i hope you need to go with newest way of configuring admob chekout its tutorial on youtube/google it i hope you will surely get answer may be your missing google play library configuration in your project hope this suggestion may help you

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply there is no ad to show.

You are making ad requests. They receive responses without error. But the response is "no ad to show".

This can be the case when you are serving ads in areas that aren't serviced well by the ad network(s) you are using. Ad fill also appears to be somewhat dependent on the amount of traffic you have. So if you are only getting a couple of hundred requests a day you may not be getting access to great/many ads.

There are 2 things you can do to rectify:

1. Increase the amount of traffic to your app
2. Use mediation to hand off to another ad network if your first choice doesn't have any ad fill.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually, my Ad unit ID is  well formatted ("ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy").  By the way, I have deleted the addTestDevice method but still not impressions.  Any other idea ? Thank you

Comment: What does your logcat say when an ad request is made?

Comment: Thank you for all ~ I will try an other ad network ~

Comment: i have an app with admob ads integrated and released on playstore live ads also coming suddenly from 2 days in my admob console showing impression 0 and no ads displayed in my android app downloaded from the play store.whats the problem please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It sometimes happens because of your app's potential.
Try to some Ad networks in Admob Mediation Group to get more impressions.